# Removing quote and hidden new line

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am reading a excel file using pd.read_excel and in one the column, few rows have quotes(") and hidden new lines. I want to remove both of them before doing some further transformation. The sample string is as follows

```
col1          col2       col3
IC201829      100234     "Valuation of GF , Francis Street D8. I number: 106698 "
```

I am using following code to remove the quote and hidden new line (between D8. and I number),

```
df['col3'] = df['col3'].str.replace('"','')
df['col3'] = df['col3'].replace(r'\\n',' ', regex=True)
```

Any suggestion is much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: see this psot:  http://www.datasciencemadesimple.com/strip-space-column-pandas-dataframe-leading-trailing-2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this way with single line `replace()`,

```
import pandas as pd
str = '''"Valuation of "GF , Francis Street D8.\nI number: 106698"'''
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col3':[str]})
print (df)

df = df.replace('\n',' ', regex=True).replace('"', '',regex=True)
print (df)
```

**RUN DEMO:** https://repl.it/@SanyAhmed/EarnestTatteredRepo

Answer (score 0):

Embed this syntax which removes next line, carriage return as well as double apostrophe.

```
df['col3'].str.replace(chr(10), "").str.replace(chr(13), "").str.replace(chr(34), "")
```

For more available options, check decimal value in [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) against the symbol which you need to replace.